# jQuery - suggestions for a "nextWhile" traversion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

jQuery currently has `.next(filter)` and `.nextAll(filter)` but I need something that fits in the middle of these - effectively, a `.nextWhile(filter)` that repeatedly does next until the filter is no longer true, then stops (rather than continuing to the end).

To demonstrate this, the following is some simplified HTML - (in reality, it is dynamically generated, random order/data, more columns, proper class names, and so on).

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="x"><td>a <button>Show/Hide</button></td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>a1</td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>a2</td></tr>

        <tr class="z"><td>b</td></tr>

        <tr class="z"><td>c</td></tr>

        <tr class="x"><td>d <button>Show/Hide</button></td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>d1</td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>d2</td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>d3</td></tr>

        <tr class="z"><td>e</td></tr>

        <tr class="x"><td>f</td></tr>

        <tr class="x"><td>g <button>Show/Hide</button></td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>g1</td></tr>
            <tr class="x y"><td>g2</td></tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And against this some JavaScript is run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j().ready(init);

    function init()
    {
        $j('tr.y').hide();
        $j('tr.x button').click( toggleRelated );
    }

    function toggleRelated()
    {
        // Only toggles one row
        // $j(this).parents('tr').next('.y').toggle();

        // Toggles unrelated ones also
        $j(this).parents('tr').nextAll('.y').toggle();

        // Not currently a jQuery construct
        // $j(this).parents('tr').nextWhile('.y').toggle();
    }

</script>
```

Is there an easy way to implement this `nextWhile` construct?

Ideally this needs to be achieved without modifying the current HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jQuery you can create `nextWhile()` equivalent using [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method and [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. Simply put, *`while (condition is true) { do something }`* is same as saying *`until (condition is false) { do something }`*.

Consider this trick example where you are required to select all `.child` elements that follow the first `.parent`:

```
<ul id="test">
  <li class="parent"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="parent"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
</ul>
```

The following code is roughly equivalent to *`.nextWhile(".child")`* and selects the three `.child` elements:

```
$("#test .parent:first").nextUntil(":not(.child)");
```

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE:*** Gave up on the recursion idea and decided to count and slice (see last example).

**Initial Attempt:**
*This code is buggy - it only returns the last two items, so doesn't work for 3+ items.*

```
jQuery.fn.nextWhile = function(f)
{
    if( this.next(f).html() )
    {
        return this.next(f).nextWhile(f).andSelf();
    }
    else
    {
        return this;
    }
};
```

**Current Version:**

```
jQuery.fn.nextWhile = function(f)
{
    var Next = this.next(f);
    var Pos = 0;

    while( Next.length > 0 )
    {
        Pos++;
        Next = Next.next(f);
    }

    return this.nextAll(f).slice(0,Pos);
}
```

This appears to work fine, but I'm not sure if there are any performance penalties to selecting everything and then slicing only a handful from it?

Comment: what about just checking this.next(f).length > 0?

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense; I want to kick myself.

Comment: Wait, this is only returning the last two items - so doesn't work if 3 or more items

Comment: If performance degrades try tweaking the selector to do the slicing for you: this.nextAll(f + ':lt(' + Pos + ')')

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
$.fn.extend({
  nextWhile: function(selector) {
    var $result = $([]);
    this.each(function() {
      var $next = $(this).next();
      while ($next.is(selector)) {
        $result = $result.add($next);
        $next = $next.next();
      }
    });
    return $result;
  }
});
```